# Java - Show multiple canvases in container

Tags: java, canvas, containers

I am pretty new to Java. I want to show multiple Canvas objects in one Container object. I don't want to use Swing components. Here is my code:

```
//===============================================================================================|
package main;
//===============================================================================================|
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
//===============================================================================================|
public class Main {
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    public Main() {
        // Create a window to draw into:
        Frame window = new Frame();
        window.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing (WindowEvent we) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        window.setSize(600,400);
        window.setVisible(true);
        //
        // Create a container for the MyCanvas instances:
        Container container = new Container();
        container.setSize(600,400);
        container.setVisible(true);
        window.add(container);
        //
        // Create 2 MyCanvas instances and add them to the container:
        // Only the first one is showing.
        MyCanvas canvas1 = new MyCanvas(75, 75);
        container.add(canvas1);
        MyCanvas canvas2 = new MyCanvas(135, 300);
        container.add(canvas2);
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main app = new Main();
    }   
//===============================================================================================|  
    public class MyCanvas extends Canvas {

        int x2;
        int y2;

        public MyCanvas (int x2, int y2) {
            this.setSize(600,400);
            this.x2 = x2;
            this.y2 = y2;
        }

        public void paint (Graphics g) {
            g.drawLine(0, 0, this.x2, this.y2);
        }
    }
//===============================================================================================|
}
//===============================================================================================|
```

The Mycanvas class just paints a line from (0,0) to the coordinate passed. It works fine for the first MyCanvas instance. However, if I add more instances, only the first MyCanvas object is showing. Can anybody tell me why this is, and what to do about it?

Thanks!

Comment: You need a layout manager. Your second container replaces your first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Container Layout is not set. Set the layout by like:

```
container.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
```